# Pregunta sobre volumenes en kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kubernetes

Buenas noches estoy empezando con kubernetes y tengo un par de preguntas y quería ver si alguien me puede ayudar:
1.como puedo montar un volumen en un cluster?
2.como puedo acceder dentro del cluster a un archivo JAR que tengo descargado?
Aun soy novato con esto entonces toda información sera valiosa, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

hay varias formas de montar volumenes en K8s, en la documentación podes encontrar los tipos soportados para el cluster. Despues de ahí tenes que elegir de que forma vas a persistir tus Pv. Te dejo la url: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/ lo mas fácil si estas empezando es hacerlo por NFS. Saludos!